# Installing Ruby Gem Not working on OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rubygems, package

I am trying to install Github Linguist ruby gem through terminal in Mac .

**I don't have enough points to upload image so please bear with me.**

This is error it is showing when I install it in terminal :-

**bash-3.2#** gem install github-linguist

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing github-linguist:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150321-444-15aw05d.rb extconf.rb
```

checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
checking for cmake... no
ERROR: CMake is required to build Rugged.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

```
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--use-system-libraries
```

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.22.1b1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/rugged-0.22.1b1/gem_make.out

Answer (score 12):

`brew install cmake` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I know you are not asking how to manager Ruby's versions.
but starting to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) will help a lot.